# How do I set a field to null in Quest Toad "Browse Database Objects" view?

Tags: database, toad

Simple question, would love a solution if there is one! I assume there has to be some keyboard shortcut that will insert a null but Google isn't helping.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I followed Brent's suggestion and got my answer: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd>.

Answer (score 4):

If you post this on Toad's mailing lists, you'll get a response from the developers themselves (or other power users):

http://www.toadsoft.com/maillist.htm

Make sure to post it in the mailing list for the product you're using (Toad for Oracle, Toad for SQL Server, Toad for MySQL, etc.)

Comment: I figured.  Those guys are serious about end user support.  It'll be a matter of time before they show up here and patrol it too.